# Farming in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the maximum number of minions one can kill at the 5, 10 and 15 minute mark?

What are some good goals on number of minions killed to aim for based on level of harass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minions spawn every 30 seconds after the 90 second mark and alternating waves have a bonus siege minion.  Including the 4:30 wave (assuming the minions got to mid-lane by 5 minutes),  45 minions will have spawned per lane.  At 9:30 it will be 110, then 14:30 puts it to 175 (65 more per 5 minutes).

I'm not sure what constitutes "good" or bad, but minion kills are only a small part of being good in lane.  I'd rather worry more about the enemy champions, trying to zone them out so they can't get kills or more importantly, experience.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the subjectivity of numbers. Playing on a farm-heavy champ like Morrigan will give you way different numbers than a ganker like Evelynn. Higher minion kills mid/late game on a ganker probably mean you're not ganking enough.

Comment: Minion kills are only part of laning, but I would argue that they're the most important part for a carry.

Comment: I would add that on high elo games, you can see the carry reach 100 minions at about 13 minutes.